# Custom attribute to handle errors

Tags: c#, error-handling, custom-attributes

I try to handle errors thanks to a custom attribute in order to do not use **try catch** everywhere. I already found a library called **PostSharp** who do it perfectly BUT this is limited to 10 target classes per project. In ASP.Net MVC there is an equivalent called **HandleErrorAttribute** but I am working on a **Console**.

Any ideas, solution or sample are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: PostSharp is best solution for such purpose i think. Did you use the payed version? PostSharp uses MSIL code which i much faster, then using reflection but i don't think you want to program MSIL by yourself. It's very complicated. Further i think you can't handle this with a customAttribute. Because what PostSharp does, is to check your Attributes and insert try-catch structures. They compile it inside you code. So you don't see it and think woow so easy this attribute. But internally if you compile it adds try-catch structures. Maybe Expression-Trees allow something similiar...

Comment: I didn't use the pay version (I don't have money). I didn't know PostSharp insert try catch at runtime and I am gonna try this solution. Keep you inform.

Comment: Yes. If you compile the compiler generates MSIL code which is then interpreted by the just in time compiler at runtime. PostSharp has a lot of handy attributes which add boilerplate code at compile time so that you don't need to program it every time. Like Try-Catch or INotifyPropertyChanged and so on. This is how it works ;) If you don't have money maybe ExpressionTrees are possible to do sth. similiar. But you have much to do then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created my own custom attribute based on the PostSharp class. The link to make it is : http://doc.postsharp.net/exception-handling